# Apache PHP command wont control Raspberry pi GPIO

Tags: php, python, linux, apache

Ok im pretty new to Raspberry Pi and Python/PHP/Apache here. Im trying to get my PHP script to run a python file i created to activate a 5v relay over my home network. In terminal via SSH i can activate the Python script and it controls my relay as it should. When i try and activate the relay via my PHP script on my web server i get nothing. My PHP script and Python script are below. Any help is greatly appreciated!

My Python code is located in /home/pi as "garagedoorleft.py"
and my PHP code is located in /var/www/html as "index.php"

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Example document</title>
</head>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['LeftOPEN']))
{
exec("sudo python /home/pi/garagedoorleft.py");
}
?>
<form method="post">
<button name="LeftOPEN">Left Door</button>&nbsp;


</form>
</html>



#!/usr/bin/python

# Import required Python libraries
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Use BCM GPIO references instead of physical pin numbers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# init list with pin numbers

pinList = [2]

# loop through pins and set mode and state to 'low'

for i in pinList: 
    GPIO.setup(i, GPIO.OUT) 
    GPIO.output(i, GPIO.HIGH)

def trigger() :
        for i in pinList:
          GPIO.output(i, GPIO.LOW)
          time.sleep(0.5) 
          GPIO.output(i, GPIO.HIGH)
          GPIO.cleanup()


try: 
    trigger()


except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print "  Quit" 
  # Reset GPIO settings
  GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: gpio typically requires sudo privledges (which I see you are calling .... but php has no TTY so it cant prompt for sudo password ... )

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure how `exec` works  with pipes and what not but I think you could do

```
exec("echo SUDO_PASSWORD_FOR_MACHINE | sudo -S -p '' python my_gpio.py")
```

this passes the sudo password via stdin to the sudo command ... Im not sure how safe it is to do something like this ...

or you could try to elevate privledges yourself

add to the top if the python script

```
 import sys,os
 if os.getuid() != 0:  # not sudo so spawn as sudo
    exit(os.system("echo SUDO_PASSWORD_FOR_MACHINE | sudo -S -p '' python %s"%sys.argv))
```

Comment: Hmmm just edited my code with that exec command (edited for my own use of course) replacing my current one with still no luck.

Comment: yeah that probably means exec isnt the right tool... ill edit another idea in a sevcond

Comment: Ok. Would this have something to do with permissions?

Comment: if it did not work with your sudo password (`raspberry`?) then `exec` does not support this type of thing .... you could try echoing the output from the `exec` call to see what failed ... I think the python method should work for sure ... I think you could just interact with the files at /sys/class/gpio without needing to be sudo (its some other group... maybe input) ... its slower but it does not require the elevated privledges of the `/dev/mem` stuff...

Comment: i think its something like `echo output> /etc/class/gpio/gpio16/direction;echo 1 > /etc/class/gpio/gpio16/value`

Comment: I fixed it by adding "www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" to my sudoers file :)